# Form auto-submitting on page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5.3

How can I stop my form from auto-submitting? Currently the controller function (deleteAccount) indicated below is executed immediately the page is loaded whereas it should only be triggered upon clicking the button.

The relevant routes:

```
Route::resource("myaccount", "MyAccountController");

Route::get("myaccount", "MyAccountController@deleteAccount");
```

The relevant Controller function:

```
public function deleteAccount(){    

    $user = \Auth::user();

    \Auth::logout();

    $user->delete();

    flash()->success("Account Deleted Successfully!");

    return redirect("/");

}
```

The relevant view code:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'MyAccountController@deleteAccount')) }}

{{ method_field('get') }}

<button type="submit">Delete Account!</button>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your function as follows

```
public function deleteAccount(){    
if(isset($_GET)){
    $user = \Auth::user();

    \Auth::logout();

    $user->delete();

    flash()->success("Account Deleted Successfully!");

    return redirect("/");
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response @Mitesh Pant. Turns out this code was just fine. The only blunder I made was "wrap" this form within another form in a vain attempt to style my form buttons. I should have just used the good old div tag! I think as a result DOM couldn't execute the hidden delete method even though it could read it.